# Formulas and issues with named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula that I'm having issues working in VBA. There's 3 named ranges:

=COUNTIFS(skill_title, A3, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 5)

The value of A3 will change with each row, so that's a relative address, but $B$1 will remain constant. I'm struggling with how to reference these 3 ranges (using .address and other methods) in the code below:

```
Dim skill_title As Variant
Dim branch As Variant
Dim skill_prof As Variant

skill_title = Sheets("Employee").Range("skill_title").Address
branch = Sheets("Employee").Range("branch").Address
skill_prof = Sheets("Employee").Range("skill_prof").Address


Range("B2:B836").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()), 3, COUNTIFS(" & skill_title & ", A2, " & branch & ", $B$1, " & skill_prof & ", 5))"
```

Right now it's throwing an error, "application-defined or object-defined error", perhaps it's because my named range address don't include the sheet name? Any suggestions?

Comment: You want `.Formula`, not `.FormulaR1C1`, btw. You're not using R1C1 references.

Comment: Nice, that actually works a lot better. I've appended the Sheet name before the range address (i.e. Employee! & skill_title), and that seems to work

Comment: Also - you can used named references, instead of the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked, based on BigBen's advice:

```
Dim skill_title As Variant
Dim branch As Variant
Dim skill_prof As Variant

skill_title = Sheets("Employee").Range("skill_title").Address
skill_title = "Employee!" & skill_title
branch = Sheets("Employee").Range("branch").Address
branch = "Employee!" & branch
skill_prof = Sheets("Employee").Range("skill_prof").Address
skill_prof = "Employee!" & skill_prof

Range("B2:B836").Formula = "=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()), 3, COUNTIFS(" & skill_title & ", A2, " & branch & ", $B$1, " & skill_prof & ", 5))"
```

Comment: Note that using the `Address` is not needed here - you can write the formula with "skill_title" instead of `Employee!A1:B200` or whatever it is. If `=COUNTIFS(skill_title, A3, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 5)` works in the sheet, then you can write that exact formula using VBA. But maybe you don't want to use the named ranges, Idk.

Comment: Good point, I did try it without .address and it works fine. I may have been using that with .formulaR1C1, and now my named ranges work fine too. Thanks!